# Count records excluding duplicates

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have an array like below, i want to count number of objects where v=="dynamictext" from the dimension without repeating value of key k.Please refer to the example below : e.g. lets say i filter by v=="y" then count should be **2** but when i filter by v=="o" count should be equal to **1** since the keys (k) are similar

```
[ 
   {
      k:"a",
      v:"y"
    },
   {
      k:"b",
      v:"o"
    },
   {
      k:"d",
      v:"y"
   },
  {
      k:"b",
      v:"o"
   }
]
```

Comment: I want to put the group to NumberDisplay to show the count